# Can we pass same login credential from one to another application in ios

Tags: ios, authentication, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, url-scheme

I have couple of application from same iTunes account that installed on my device. Once I login first application means that credential will take the second one? without login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can if you have developed both apps.

You can save the login credentials in the keychain, this should always be the place to save any credentials. In the other app you can pickup the credentials from keychain again.

You will need to add the keychain to the app entitlements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How we get that credential in application? Do we have any code for that?

Comment: You use the keychain API, [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can you'll need to use the keychain
This is a helper wrapper that I've used before for keychain otherwise its nasty C based code.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain